In AOSP Android 13 is there any way to pre-grant accessibility permissions to a prebuilt app package which is system priv-app
Hey i have been working on building a rom which is based on Android 13 for pixel 4a 5g . Basically my problem is that i want pregrant accessibility permission and screen capture permission for an Assist APK which is included as system priv-app is there any way to pregrant the permission on startup itself
i tried using init.rc then i can enable the accessibility but this can be turned off by the user. In my specific case is should be always enabled

This is the right way to pre-grant permissions: https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/runtime_perms#creating-exceptions.
But an accessibility service isn't controlled by a permission. A service is enabled if it's in this list in settings: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java;drc=ad46de2aa9707021970cb929d016b639f98a1ac7;l=8615.
Modify the code maintaining that setting to pre-enable your service. Or using the existing defaultAccessibilityService configuration (set it with a product overlay file) might work.
The simplest way to stop a user from turning it off is probably to modify the accessibility settings UI.
